# How do I add an image in a Meteor template file?

Tags: html, meteor, iron-router

I am currently making a Meteor website with multiple pages and using IronRouter to have my `/client/main.html` display a page frame and import several HTML templates located in `/imports/ui`.  I have an HTML `<img>` element located inside one of the templates-- `/imports/ui/home.html`.

Where do I need to put the image file and what do I need to put as the `href=` to find the image properly?

I have already tried both using a `/public` directory, and putting the image in the `/imports/ui` file and then trying to link to it with both the image name itself (as if the template were calling the image from its own folder) and using `/../imports/ui/image.jpg` as if `main.html` (the page with the frame and Ironrouter links) were calling the image file.

Answer (score 1):

1. Put your image file (e.g., `image.png`) in `/public`.
2. Use `<img src="/image.png"/>` in your html (note: `img` tags use `src` not `href` attributes -- an easy mistake to make).

More details [here](https://guide.meteor.com/structure.html#special-directories).